# Nova - ManyToMany with additional relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-nova, laravel-relations

So, we have a `contacts` table and a `projects` table, with a many to many relationship. the pivot table `contact_project` has a `answer_type_id` so it belongsTo `AnswerType`, and it also HasMany `sendings`.

I'm trying to allow content people to link contacts to projects. So I added:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Projects')
                ->fields(function ($request, $relatedModel) {
                    return [
                        BelongsTo::make('Answer type'),
                        DateTime::make('Answered at')
                    ];
                }),
```

And I also tried to define the belongsTo as `BelongsTo::make('Answer type', 'answerType', ContactProject::class)` but to no avail : `Call to undefined method App\Models\Contact::answerType()`.

I would be grateful for a little help :) Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's simply not supported: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/5334#issuecomment-1435691794 or https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/5173#issuecomment-1357614020